# Change components background using ref - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have just started to learn React Native(from android background). I want to change View's background color. I need to do it without using state/props as i do not want to render it again.

I have ref ed the view and able to access it using another button's onPress()

How can I change the background of the view?

Answer (score 4):

Set the ref:

```
ref={component => this.myref = component}
```

and set the background using setNativeProps

```
this.myref.setNativeProps({
    style:{backgroundColor: '#3fba29'}
});
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Before you use it, try to solve your problem with setState .

https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation

In single value it very easy

```
ChangeBackground(){
 this.setState({
  backgroundColor:'blue'
 )}
}
render() {
 return (  
<View onPress={()=>this.ChangeBackground()}style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
  ....
 </View>
```

In array data you have to work with index value. Update background color with the help of index or id

something like this,

```
const original = this.state.array;
const single_array = this.state.array.find(
    x => x.id === id,
);
single_array.backgroundColor = 'blue';
original[index] = single_array;
this.setState({
    array: original,
});
```